# Formula for calculating markup with big % for small amounts and small % for larger amounts

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

I am trying to come up with a formula for calculating markup for products that range in value from a few cents up to tens of Dollars.

At 10c I would like the markup to be around 500%, and from 2 Dollars upwards I would like it to be 30%. In between 10c and 2 Dollars I would like the markup to diminish proportionally.

I came up with the following (computer code) but for some reason it is not working well.

```
if (cost < 2)
{
    markup = (((2 - cost) / 2) * 370) + 30;
}
else
{
    markup = 30;
}

return cost * (1 + (markup / 100));
```

It would be great if the markup could be on a curve where at 10c the markup is big, but diminishes very quickly so even by 30c it is not so huge.

Can someone help with some building blocks I can use to produce the required result, probably with how to adjust the curve until I get some figures that I am happy with?

I think I might also need some assistance with tagging this appropriately. (Sorry)

Comment: Do you want the markup to continue to decrease to less than 30% as the price increases, or do you want it to hold steady at the 30% markup?

Comment: @EthanHunt, hold steady at 30%, but I can do that with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the points you have provided, one such formula for the type of scenario you are looking for is $M(p)=0.575p^{-0.939}$. For both prices $p=0.1$ and $p=2$, the error is fairly minimal. This function will also continue to decrease the markup as price increases, but if you want the markup to remain constant after the price hits $2, you can specify that in your code.

Comment: I tried `0.575 * (cost ^ -0.939)` - is that right as it doesn't seem to give the right result? And, can I ask what the numbers 0.575 and -0.939 represent so that I can try and understand this.

Comment: It doesn't give exact results, but $M(0.1)=4.99652$, or just about a 500% markup, and $M(2)=0.299917$, or about a 30% markup. The key would be interpreting the decimal results as percentages. The two values I used came from Excel when I asked it to fit a curve to the two points $(0.1,5)$ and $(2,0.3)$. To my knowledge, there isn't anything special about them.